# vba updating named range cells

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to write functiona that will give you the closest city from a list to a given coordinate or the state depending on a boolean value. here is what I have

```
Function GetCity(x As String, Optional b as Boolean) As String
    Dim i As Long, count As Long, row As Long
    Dim min As Double

     Count = Range("Table_IVO").Rows.Count
     min = 9999999

     For i = 1 To Count
         If dist(x, Range("Table_IVO")(i,1).Value) < min Then
             min = dist(x, Range("Table_IVO")(i,1).Value)
             row = i
         End If
     Next i

     If b = True Then
         GetCity = Range("Table_IVO")(row, 3).Value
     Else
         GetCity = Range("Table_IVO")(row, 2).Value
     End If
End Function
```

The table is set as so

```
   A      B     C
Coords  City  State
```

It gets in the loop but never loops? It dies before even executing the if

Comment: What is **dist()** ??

Comment: The "Funciton" could be the most ridiculous mistake.

Comment: Why don't you debug your code using step into (`F8` key)! What do you mean it gets in the loop but never loops?

Comment: This is not the actual code, its on a closed system i had to retype it here, so the function misspelling is not a problem in the actual code. dist is a is a simple trig function that calculates the distance between two points. It works as intended as I see the result from if i print to debug. It only ever runs the dist function once is the main issue. it never loops through the list comparing the results

Comment: @JLILIAman - you will have to forgive me I am a PHP/JS programmer and VBA is still relatively new to me I am still trying to figure out the debugging aspects

Comment: can you insert this line `msgbox(count)` after `min = 9999999` and debug it?Let's see what you get it.

Comment: i have several debug print lines that i have tried inserting. count = 44

Answer (score 0):

```
     If b = True Then
        GetCity = Range("Table_IVO")(row, 3).Value
     Else
        GetCity = Range("Table_IVO")(row, 2).Value
     End
```

Though I might get more clarity by looking at complete code, but if this is exactly your code which u are executing, then probably you missed writing **If** at the end of **End** in the last line of your code sample, as in

```
     If b = True Then
        GetCity = Range("Table_IVO")(row, 3).Value
     Else
        GetCity = Range("Table_IVO")(row, 2).Value
     End If
```

Depending on the environment you are executing your code, it may not show a compilation error.

Comment: ill have to check tomorrow to be certain, but doubt that is the case as the excel would have flagged that, its probably just a typo upon writing it up on here. Besides the function is not even reaching that point as I have stated it does not leave the loop.... It runs the dist function once but then stops. Their is no error. I added a couple debug prints to be certain and it makes it into the loop but never into the if... I check the output of dist and it reads out fine at around 1000 which is less than min at the start so it should make it into the if.